# What might cause a docker container to execute an su command differently on two hosts?

Tags: macos, centos, docker, su

We have an example of a docker container that will happily execute `su hdfs` when run on boot2docker on Mac OSX, but will refuse to do so when run on CentOS.
Can anyone explain how this might happen?